# WPF adjacent shape aliasing artifacts

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a rendering issue when trying to render two adjacent shapes in WPF. Using two polygons that have the same coordinates for the edges I hoped to see it filled nicely blue in this case. However there is a thin line from the background visible between the two polygons.

When I set the SnapToDevicePixels property to true the problem seems to be solved for the polygons that are vertically adjacent but not for the diagonal adjacent polygons.

Is it possible to solve this problem without combining the two polygons into one?

[image: SnapToDevicePixels off]

[image: SnapToDevicePixels on]

Comment: Perhaps you can have each part overlap the other for a pixel or so?

Comment: You can design this figure using one single [path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms747393%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @Tom that might be a viable workaround indeed!

Comment: @Erik that is possible but because of draw order dependencies I have to draw them seperately so combining them is not an option for me.

Comment: There is another property that you can try to use: [UseLayoutRounding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.uselayoutrounding%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: #Erik tried it but the result is the same